# error al guardar información desde un Combobox al datagridview en c#

Tags: c#

Hola a todos nuevamente necesito de su ayuda, tengo un problema al querer guardar un nuevo elemento en mi aplicación este me arroja el siguiente error que dejare en una imagen que hice, llevo días tratando de dar con el problema y siempre me da el mismo error. Los 2 Combobox cargan todos los datos desde la base de datos perfectamente.espero que con estos ejemplos propuesto me puedan ayudar con dicho código, ver donde esta mi error, muchas gracias a los que se detengan a leer mi ayuda y muchas gracias a lo que dediquen un poco de su tiempo queriéndome ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor si alguien me puede ayudar, aquí le dejo el código del botón guardar
los Combobox cargan bien desde la tabla de la base de datos de cada uno.

```
   //objeto Entidad 
    CEFajillas objEntidad = new CEFajillas();
    
    //variable
        private bool Editarse = false;




// BOTON GUARDAR / 
        private void pbxGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Editarse == false)
            {
                try
                {
objEntidad.Nombre = txtNombre.Text.ToUpper();
objEntidad.IdUnidad = Convert.ToInt32(cbxUnidad.SelectedValue); //linea 283
objEntidad.Precio = txtPrecio.Text.ToUpper();
objEntidad.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Value);
objEntidad.IdProveedor = Convert.ToInt32(cbxProveedor.SelectedValue);

                    objNegocio.InsertandoFajillas(objEntidad);

                    MessageBox.Show("Se guardo el registro");
                    mostrarBuscarTabla("");
                    //limpiar cajas de texto
                    limpiarTextBox();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se pudo guardar el registro" + ex);
                }
            }

            if (Editarse == true)
            {
                try
                {
     objEntidad.IdFajillas = Convert.ToInt32(idFajillas);
     objEntidad.Nombre = txtNombre.Text.ToUpper();
     objEntidad.IdUnidad = Convert.ToInt32(cbxUnidad.SelectedValue);
     objEntidad.Precio = txtPrecio.Text.ToUpper();
     objEntidad.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Value);
     objEntidad.IdProveedor = Convert.ToInt32(cbxProveedor.SelectedValue);

          objNegocio.EditandoFajillas(objEntidad);

          MessageBox.Show("Se edito el registro");
              Editarse = false;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se pudo editar el registro" + ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

ahora mi CapaEntidad, Clase CEFajillas

```
    namespace CapaEntidades
    {
        public class CEFajillas
        {
            private int _idFajillas;
            private string _Codigo;
            private string _Nombre;
            private int _idUnidad;
            private string _Precio;
            private DateTime _Fecha;
            private int _idProveedor;
    
            public int IdFajillas { get => _idFajillas; set => _idFajillas = value; }
            public string Codigo { get => _Codigo; set => _Codigo = value; }
            public string Nombre { get => _Nombre; set => _Nombre = value; }
            public int IdUnidad { get => _idUnidad; set => _idUnidad = value; }
            public string Precio { get => _Precio; set => _Precio = value; }
            public DateTime Fecha { get => _Fecha; set => _Fecha = value; }
            public int IdProveedor { get => _idProveedor; set => _idProveedor = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como estas asignando los valores al combo box?
cual va al valuemember y al displaymember?

En la fecha podrias cambiar el textbox a un DateTimePicket y asignaro mas facil 
dtpFecha.Value y asi no conviertes nada.

Intenta agregar al final del combo 
objEntidad.IdProveedor = Convert.ToInt32(cbxProveedor.SelectedValue.toString());

tambien seria de buena ayuda ver el objEntidad

Comment: Tambien te dice que no puedes convertir un objeto a un entero

objEntidad.IdFajillas = Convert.ToInt32(idFajillas.toString());

Intentalo a ver si te ayuda a asigarle el valor porque ahi le estas mandando un objeto no un string o algo que pueda convertirse

Comment: Saludos. Lo más que puedo orientarte es que el error ocurre dentro de `if (Editarse == false)`; la línea **283** a simple vista no se puede determinar cual es; puede ser algunos de los `Convert.ToInt32` incluso la asignación en `objEntidad.Precio`; ahora bien, te sugiero coloques un **breakpoint** y verifiques los valores que se quieren convertir.

Comment: @Chistian GTZ gracias por tu ayuda, pero mi problema u}aun persiste igual y en verdad lo que tengo es un DateTimePicket enmi txtFecha

Comment: @RobertiLeOr gracias también por tu sugerencia y si en verdad fue un error de mi parte no comentar cual es la linea 283, la cual es  **objEntidad.IdUnidad = Convert.ToInt32(cbxUnidad.SelectedValue); **

Comment: Como estas guardando los datos en la db

con una consulta directa o un Procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Hola @ChristianGtz aun sigo con mi problema, aquí dejare un lino del proyecto, por si me podría ayudar con el problema ......... 
       [ https://mega.nz/file/c5EF3SJY#L5GOvK9mpS1EeT3L5Xclm-3O5jqyiY0bGOTmMpWkasc ]

Comment: olvide agregar los datos de la base de datos están aquí [ https://mega.nz/file/Ig1XSBab#XKJJhlrVfL8SvH-uf1Gl6kea2sDQNcAdhrK1iV6kIT8 ]

Comment: Hola @Alynson mandame un correo, ya lo estoy revisando 
christiangtzv@gmail.com

Comment: Puedes pasarme tambien las tablas de Unidad y Proveedor

Comment: @ChristianGtz he vuelto después de mucho tiempo, el covid-19 cambio muchas cosas al mi alrededor, tengo algo pendiente contigo, en los próximo días me pongo al dia, porque ya mi vida ha vuelto a tomar el ritmo normal